# App crashes after adding the AdSupport.framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, ios6

Hi I get this error on startup:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/AdSupport.framework/AdSupport
  Referenced from: /Users/owner12/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/823A0485-7443-4206-B9F5-A84C03DBFB89/BusinessPlan.app/BusinessPlan
  Reason: image not found
```

I added that framework to the Target --> Build Phases --> Link Binary With Libraries.

The strange thing is that this framework started appearing in my project in the navigator in the main area where the files are, and not in the project/Frameworks.

Would anyone know how to fix this?  Thanks!

Also, I added some params to the Build Settings under "Other Linker Flags" and they appear like this:

[image]

But really they were supposed to appear like this:

```
-all_load *
-ObjC
```

Could that be the reason for the error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

" Referenced from: /Users/owner12/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/**5.1**/" - isn't AdSupport available [only in iOS 6.0 and later](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS6.html)?

Comment: yes, here is what my instructions say: AdSupport.framework - Required for iOS6, but for compatibility with pre-iOS6, make this link Optional. Only necessary if you're using Xcode version 4.5 or above

Comment: find this framework in "Link Binary With Libraries" build phase and change "required" to "optional"